# Pandas concat a row after group by and then resample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have the following dataframe:

```
df dataframe: 
      item   date_buy    date_sell     profit window
1     shoes  2009-12-04  2021-08-14    0.22     10
2     shoes  2009-12-05  2010-09-19    1.5      10
3     shoes  2015-05-05  2020-15-15    7.3      10
4     shoes  2009-12-09  2021-08-14    0.82     4
5     shoes  2009-12-10  2010-09-20    4.5      4
6     shoes  2015-05-11  2020-15-16    1.8      4
7     hat    2009-12-04  2021-08-14    1.2      10
8     hat    2009-12-05  2010-09-19    2.25     10
9     hat    2015-05-05  2020-15-15    4.3      10
10    hat    2009-12-09  2021-08-14    3.2      4
11    hat    2009-12-10  2010-09-20    9.4      4
12    hat    2015-05-11  2020-15-16    1.8      4
```

What I need to do is to resample the data until today using `data_buy` as a key and separating the data by `item` and `window`. What I did is grouping my data by `item` and `window`, for each group I add the an extra row exactly as the last of the group changing only `data_buy` field with today date and then resample but the execution is extremely slow since I have several thousands of data.

this is my code:

```
    data = data.set_index(pd.to_datetime(data ['date_buy']))
    resampled_data = data.groupby(['item', 'window']).apply(lambda x: resample(x, now())
    
def resample(df, today):
    df = pd.concat([df, df[df.index==df.index.max()].rename(index={df.index.max(): pd.to_datetime(today)})])
    df = df.asfreq('B', method='ffill')
    return df
```

the result is correct and is the following (it's similar for the item hat):

```
df dataframe: 
      item   date_buy    date_sell     profit window
1     shoes  2009-12-04  2021-08-14    0.22     10
2     shoes  2009-12-05  2010-09-19    1.5      10
.
2     shoes  2015-05-04  2010-09-19    1.5      10
3     shoes  2015-05-05  2020-15-15    7.3      10
.
.
3     shoes  2022-09-15  2020-15-15    7.3      10
4     shoes  2009-12-09  2021-08-14    0.82     4
5     shoes  2009-12-10  2010-09-20    4.5      4
.
5     shoes  2015-05-10  2010-09-20    4.5      4
6     shoes  2015-05-11  2020-15-16    1.8      4
.
.
6     shoes  2022-09-15  2020-15-16    1.8      4
```

This snippet takes about 30s to execute and I wanted to make it faster. Am I missing some pandas best practice to make it faster?

Answer (score 2):

I might have a solution without `.apply`:

**First step** - Create a dataframe `end_data` that contains the closing `date_buy` entries for each `item`-`window` group:

```py
today = pd.Timestamp.today().floor('D')
end_data = (
    data
    .groupby(['item', 'window'], as_index=False)
    .agg({'date_buy': lambda c: today})
)
```

For your sample that looks like:

```
    item  window   date_buy
0    hat       4 2022-09-15
1    hat      10 2022-09-15
2  shoes       4 2022-09-15
3  shoes      10 2022-09-15
```

**Second step**:

```
data['date_buy'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_buy'])  # Just in case
data = (
    pd.concat([data, end_data])
    .set_index('date_buy', drop=True).sort_index()
    .groupby(['item', 'window'], as_index=False).resample('B').ffill()
    .fillna(method='ffill')
    .droplevel(0).reset_index()
)
```

- Cast column `date_buy` into `datetime`s (might already be the case).
- Append `end_data` at the end of `data`.
- Use column `date_buy` as index (drop the column), and then sort the index. The sorting is only necessary if the `item`-`window` blocks of `date_buy` aren't already in ascending order.
- Now group the result by `item`-`window`, `.resample('B')` on the groups to upsample according to your requirement, and use `.ffill` on the results.
- Then fill the remaining `NaN`/`NaT`s via forward fill.
- Finally drop the first index level, and reset the upsampled `date_buy`-index as a column.

The result for your sample looks like:

```
        date_buy   item   date_sell  profit  window
0     2009-12-09    hat  2021-08-14     3.2       4
1     2009-12-10    hat  2010-09-20     9.4       4
2     2009-12-11    hat  2010-09-20     9.4       4
3     2009-12-14    hat  2010-09-20     9.4       4
4     2009-12-15    hat  2010-09-20     9.4       4
...          ...    ...         ...     ...     ...
13329 2022-09-09  shoes  2020-15-15     7.3      10
13330 2022-09-12  shoes  2020-15-15     7.3      10
13331 2022-09-13  shoes  2020-15-15     7.3      10
13332 2022-09-14  shoes  2020-15-15     7.3      10
13333 2022-09-15  shoes  2020-15-15     7.3      10

[13334 rows x 5 columns]
```

(Column `date_sell` contains invalid dates.)

Comment: I've been finally able to try this solution, thanks a lot for the time! It is actually a 20% faster with a big chunk of data and I think it all makes sense, the problem is that `data` at the end of the computation has a 10% of the rows that differ from my initial solution. I'm trying to investigate why.

Comment: @RobertoLandi Thanks for the feedback! I would be interested in what you find out.